# Is Flux Architecture an alternative to MVC, or do they not exclude each other?

Tags: model-view-controller, redux, architecture, flux

Is Flux Architecture an alternative to MVC, or do they not exclude each other? I am not sure I completely understand both concepts. I would like to use flux/redux in my macOS app, but it seems structurally made for MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flux was primarily made for React, where the unidirectional data flow is useful for component based applications. MVC on the other hand is bidirectional where the controllers handle all the business logic.

[This](https://syndicode.com/2017/09/19/flux-vs-mvc/) will be a good read to understand the differences between both and help you choose the right framework for your app.